# Symfony ManyToMany how fetch object related to another object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I don’t understand how to access Product related to CartLine.

I have two entities

**CartLine entity:**

```
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="cartLines")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="cart_line_product")
     */
    private $product;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->product = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProduct(): Collection
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
```

**Product entity:**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CartLine", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $cartLines;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cartLines = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @return Collection|CartLine[]
     */
    public function getCartLines(): Collection
    {
        return $this->cartLines;
    }
```

Next, I add the product to the basket through the form, like this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $cartLine = new CartLine();
            $cartLine->addProduct($product);

            $em->persist($cartLine);
            $em->flush();
```

Product is added as expected.

Then I try to display the products in the basket:

```
       $id = $this->getUser()->getCart()->getId();
        $cartline = $cartLineRepo->findAllCartLineByUser($id);
```

then in template

```
{% for cart in cartline.id %} //OR {% for cart in cartline.product.id %}
 <div class="item">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I get an error 
`Key "id" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3" does not exist`

Or a call in the controller

```
$cart = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CartLine::class)->findAll();
        foreach ($cart as $value){
            $id = $value->getProduct()->getId();
        }
```

I get an error  `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getId" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".`

How can I get a related object or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ManyToMany` relation here, not a `ManyToOne` (Many cart to one product)

Thus, `$value->getProduct()` return an `ArrayCollection`, not a single `product`.
Which is why `getId()` isn't working, because it's not a `product` object.

I get the feeling that you're more in needs of a `ManyToOne <=> OneToMany` relation than a `ManyToMany`

If you're sure that you need a `ManyToMany` relation, then here is how should be your code

```
$cartLines=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CartLine::class)->findAll();

foreach($cartLines as $cartLine) {
    $products=$cartLine->getProduct(); //ArrayCollection

    foreach($products as $product) {
        $id=$product->getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that I am receiving a collection, I just thought about it for too long and could not find a solution.
Thanks anyway. 
PS:  I need ManyToMany because I have User which OneToOne with Cart, which OneToMany with CartLine, which ManyToMany related to Product.